# ES File Explorer - Share by LAN

Tags: share-menu, es-file-explorer

I want to use **ES File Explorer's** LAN share feature in the **Share via** options in Android to send files to my PC that you can currently only do by going into the app itself - a rather long process.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned below, I posted a request to the Developer about being able to send files to your PC through the "Share via" menu - this would be a shortcut/alternative to opening up the ES File Explorer app and manually copy and pasting from your phone memory to the LAN PC...

**This feature is now added!** Anywhere on android, click a file, picture, video or pretty much anything that can be moved or copied, click the "Share" button, then click the "ES Save to..." option, and choose your path on your PC. It will now be copied directly to your computer using the LAN feature inside the ES File Explorer app.

[image]

Enjoy :)

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to use "share by lan"?  If you just want to read/write files to a network you don't need to use that feature.

Comment: Well I'm not exactly writing files to the network, I'm transferring files between my Phone and PC using the home router. I prefer ES File Explorer as it uses Samba technology so I don't need any third-party software installed on my PC, just ES File Explorer on my phone is sufficient. Atm, im having to open the ES File Explorer, go to LAN, find my PC, then copy files then paste them using ES File Explorer. This is a bit long. If they added a new feature called Send to PC using LAN, it would cut so much work out. I could just select file anywhere, hit share, and send through the Send Via menu.

Comment: What I've done is added frequently used locations on my network as favourites.  It's then easy to open up ES, click on the favourite to get a file listing(of a folder within a samba share), then open another window within ES and use another favourite to quickly get to my sd card; I can easily navigate between windows and multi-select files to copy/delete etc.

Comment: Set up favourites within ES File Explorer? You mean like picture 1 above? I've added my pc (named "0.4"). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Click on that icon and navigate to the folder above the one you'd like to be a favourite. So if you have something like "192.168.1.100/c$/mine/music/rock" and you want "rock" as a favourite location navigate to "music", then long press on "rock", select it, click on "more", then "add to favourites" and it'll appear in your favourite list. Drag from the left to see your various locations, including favourites.  Hope this is clear, if not ask me again!

Comment: Oh wow, that's neat :) Than you, works great.

Comment: No worries. Actually, forget that `drag from the left` thing; it's the little phone/globe icon at the top left, isn't it.

Comment: Thanks mate, I got Samsung s3 so I don't have to tap the Globe button nor Slide, menu shows by hitting the Menu Softkey. :)

Comment: Good stuff! Glad to have helped. Now get out there and kick ass!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a reply from ES File Explorer team, they said that the "Share by LAN" feature in the "Share via" is not for sending files to the PC, it is for sending files to **other devices** which has **ES File Explorer** running on them, on the same network.

I've requested a new feature that allows you to send to the PC through Share via, but if they decide to build it, it may take a while still before it's out.

Comment: Feature is now added as outlined by @jclariviere

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this was added in a recent release of ES File Explorer, but you can share to computer with:

```
Share via -> ES Save to... -> Click on the header (under "Choose path")
```

Your LAN shares should appear there.

Comment: you're correct. The feature is now added.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than simply transferring files is to set up ES File Explorer's "Remote Access" in settings.

This turns the android device into an FTP file server with username and password.

Once running, you can use any FTP client (such as FileZilla) to connect to the Android device and access the android's full SD card(s) file system for transferring files back and forth.

The BIG advantage is that you are able to control all transfers using only the PC's keyboard, mouse and monitor.

Further, ES can create a desktop shortcut for the FTP server, so, any time you need to transfer files in either direction, simply tap the icon on the Android home screen, then click a FileZilla command line shortcut on your PC (`filezilla -c, --site=sitenamestring`)

Two "gotchas" to know about;

1. IP addresses change on your home or other LANs. Your best bet is to set your WiFi up to assign fixed IP addresses to your mobile devices so you can have a saved entry with username, password and starting file directory for instant connection from your PC.
2. file date/time stamps don't transfer. Any files copied to your Android device will bear the date/time that the file was transferred